# Allow to accept more than one answers to a question

Tags: feature-request, answers, accepted-answer

Some questions are so vast topic in Hinduism and may have more than one answers.  So it should be allowed to accept more than one answer.

Comment: Is this your feature request asking to get an option to select multiple answers or are you asking a support question if you can select multiple answers to a question?

Comment: No such feature doesn't exist. We can accept only a single answer. However accepted answer doesn't necessarily mean correct answer. It indicates that is more helpful answer the user got like a best answer (to user) among many other.

Comment: No, as said [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40202/260388), you can't mark multiple answers as accepted. You can upvote any answer and you may also start and offer bounty to another answers!

Answer (score 5):

Only one answer should be allowed to be accepted. Usually OP selects the best answer among all and as the superlative suggests "best" cannot be many!

Also, giving of +15 reputation with an acceptance, easily may create bloating of reputations. Because there is no minimum reputation requirement to accept an answer (upvote=15, downvote=125).

BTW, if user changes mind, then that answer can be "un-accepted" -- by re-clicking the right tick mark OR by accepting another answer.

Similar post in main meta:
[Accept Multiple Answers or Split Bounty among Several Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2786/163449)

Answer (score 0):

Mark answer doesn't merely imply being correct one. It actually implies being the **best answer**. In SE communities all answers should be correct one which are called accepted. You mark the best answer from these many valid/acceptable/correct answer.

Comment: Best according to OP not universally or absolutely.

Comment: Yo bro @Rickross

Comment: "In SE communities all answers should be correct one which are called accepted." What do you mean by this statement?

Comment: @TheDestroyer accepted - correct one. Marked one is best.